# Manual type cast in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Before rails 4.2, I could write:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(:dummy, nil, type.to_s).type_cast(value)
```

To type cast `value` to `type`, but now that API seems to have changed a lot. How can I do it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data_type = :integer.to_s.camelize
ActiveRecord::Type.const_get(data_type).new.send :cast_value, "50.0"
```

Comment: Instead of calling the private `cast_value`, call `type_cast_from_user` instead.